# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'" using LinkedIN API in Angular 6

Tags: angular, api, rxjs, linkedin-api, angular6

I am trying to make a simple API call on the LinkedIN API in my Angular application. My API key and all that is perfect. For some reason when my app calls this function I am getting this error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap"

I even added the line:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

to the top of this component.

Here is my component.ts in total:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LinkedInService } from 'angular-linkedin-sdk';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'LItest';
  public apiKey;
  private basicProfileFields = ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'maiden-name', 'formatted-name', 'phonetic-first-name', 'phonetic-last-name', 'formatted-phonetic-name', 'headline', 'location', 'industry', 'picture-url', 'positions'];
  public lastResponse;


  public constructor(private _linkedInService: LinkedInService) {
  }

  public rawApiCall(){
    const url = '/people/~?format=json';
    this._linkedInService.raw(url)
      .asObservable()
        .subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          },
          complete: () => {
            console.log('RAW API call completed');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular6 uses **rxjs6.0.0+**, and for that , you can import operators by `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'`, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/6.2.2#es6-via-npm

Comment: I got another error. This was for sure the fix and I appreciate the documentation to go along with the solution.

Comment: The next error was "ERROR TypeError: this.isLoadedObservable.switchMap is not a function
    at FluentApiCall.push../node_modules/angular-linkedin-sdk/src/fluent.api.call.js.FluentApiCall.asObservable"

Comment: `switchMap` such operators are called pipeable operators, just use them at `pipe` method. You can still find sample on above link and see also https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md. :-)

Comment: I did read the documentation. Can't figure out a solution to fit into my code above

Comment: To those who want to help, I think you may have to post piece of code for `this.isLoadedObservable.switchMap` part.

Comment: That line is not in my code. I added console.log(this._linkedInService.raw(url)) and got a FluentApiCall. I am working based off of the LinkedIn API Angular SDK and that line is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-linkedin-sdk

Comment: This package is developed based on rxjs5, not rxjs6. There are conflicts between Angular6 and this package.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: There is already a PR on progress, you can upgrade to use rxjs6 in that package yourself or simply wait for that PR to be merged.

Comment: That is great! This may be too simple of a question @Pengyy, but how do I upgrade to use that PR?

Comment: **It's not recommended** but if you can't wait then just fork from the PR repository, and install from local with npm.

Answer (score 8):

Try to install

**`npm install --save rxjs-compat`**